# Url refresh and reload not working after removing # sign from url angularjs

Tags: angularjs, url-rewriting, pretty-urls

> My app.js

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'interests.html',
        controller: 'InterestsController'
    })
    .when('/interests',{
        templateUrl: 'interests.html',
        controller: 'InterestsController'
    })
    .when('/subjects',{
        templateUrl: 'subjects.html',
        controller: 'SubjectsController'
    })
    .when('/prequalification',{
        templateUrl: 'prequalification.html',
        controller: 'PreQualificationController'
    })
    .when('/qualification',{
        templateUrl: 'qualification.html',
        controller: 'QualificationController'
    })
    .when('/personalinfo',{
        templateUrl: 'personalinfo.html',
        controller: 'PersonalInfoController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/interests'
    });
    if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
}]);
```

> In index.html file. Path to index.html file: localhost:8080/cf/. All of the other views also resides with index.html

```
<base href="/cf/">
```

> .htaccess file content(path to .htaccess file: localhost:8080/cf/.htaccess)

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]


    RewriteRule ^ cf/index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

> Path to my project folder on server is: localhost:8080/cf. I have various rules in .htaccess file from other posts of stackoverflow but nothing is working. When even i reload or refresh the page, i get 404. With out refreshing and reloading everything is working fine. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Add this in app config**

```
if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

**Step 2: Add this in index.html file**

```
<base href="/your-app-name">
```

**Step 3: Add .htaccess file on root directory**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<base href="/cf">
```

in document "head" section.

Hope this helps!!